# firestore query a value under a subfield under field asterisk star

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this data:

```
{ 
  root: { 
    _rEG: { fen: 'value' }, 
    _AS: { fen: 'value' }, 
    _BSSA: { fen: 'value' } 
  }
}
```

I want to query like `where('root.*.fen', '==', 'value')`.
How can I do this.

I thought about putting all fen values as keys and value to this * path and index like that, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use a wildcard in the field name in a query.

To implement this use-case, you can:

- Either create a top-level field with all `fen` values ([using an `array-union`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)), and query with `array-contains` against that field.
- Or put the `_rEG`, `_AS` and `_BSSA` in documents in a dedicated subcollection, and query against that with a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).